# Excel user form changing date format when writing to table

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I am making a user form to make adding data to a table easier. The problem I have in the below is TextBox3. This textbox will default to todays date and correctly shows dd/mm/yyyy format
The problem is when it writes to the table if the day is <13 it is converting writing the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. if the day is >12 it writes it correctly as dd/mm/yyyy

```
sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
sh.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
sh.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
sh.Range("H" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
sh.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value`
```

I have tried looking through other examples similar to this question but because my knowledge of VBA is so limited I have not been able to make any suggestions I found work

Comment: The textbox is a text that looks like a date.  When you move it to excel, it tries to convert it to a date.  store the date in the textbox as yyyy-mm-dd then it will convert to a date correctly, then make sure you format the target cell(s) as you want them to display.

Comment: or if you want to leave it as is then use(assuming TextBox1 is the date):`=DateSerial(cdbl(Split(Me.TextBox1.Value,"/")(2)),cdbl(Split(Me.TextBox1.Value,"/")(1)),cdbl(Split(Me.TextBox1.Value,"/")(0)))`